# What is new since Family.Show?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am relatively new to WPF and have been looking at [Family.Show](http://familyshow.codeplex.com/). It looks like a great reference application, but it has not been updated since February 2009. When I am looking through this code, are there any outdated techniques in here or improvements in the platform that I should be aware of?

[Edit] I have gotten a number of responses about PRISM and MVVM. I can now see how this question was not clear. Family.Show is one of the few WPF applications that I think really looks like a nice WPF application. I would like to use it as a model, but am concerned that the XAML and controls that they use might have been replaced with newer elements. Would someone give me some guidance in this respect?

[Edit] I should mention that I have read WPF 4 almost in its entirety, but not having much experience actually writing WPF applications, it is not easy for me to spot old or outdated technologies in something like Family.Show.

Comment: Nowadays you would normally employ MVVM to create any WPF application. Unfortunatelly, this sample makes no use whatsoever of MVVM.

Comment: Thank you @DanielHilgarth, separating my logic between view and other has been an expertise of mine for some time. I have my own framework for that. I am more interested in what has changed in WPF.

Comment: In WPF itself? I don't think that there were a lot of changes. Surely not in terms of the basics like DataTemplates, Binding, Styles etc. The only thing that changed is that there are more controls present out of the box than was the case back in 2009.

Comment: Thank you @DanielHilgarth, that was my belief and this question is my way of confirming it. Now I can study this application with confidence :->

Comment: Yes, you certainly can do that. Not so much with regards to the architecture, but with regards to the WPF side of things.

Comment: I put all that in an answer, so others can benefit from it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the WPF side of things, not much has changed since 2009.
There are still DataTemplates, Styles, Data binding etc. They are used just like they have been used back then.

In the current version of the .NET framework a few more controls are present out of the box, so you might find some user controls in that example that are no longer necessary. However, the existing controls haven't changed as far as I know.

However, that application doesn't make any use of MVVM, which I personally find a big drawback.
So, you can use the application as a means to study WPF, but you shouldn't adept its architecture style in your own applications.

Answer (score 1):

I think Prism is a very good framework to build enterprise(bigger) applications but at first sight it could be a little difficult. If you are new to WPF but want to get to know the WPF and MVVM better, check http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/ or http://waf.codeplex.com/. (With them it is a little easer to understand the principles.) You can get the source too and it is a good documentation to both, so you can learn a lot.

I think it is important to be familiar with the MVVM principles as a WPF developer.
I can suggest to you to watch the following two video from MIX conferences too:

http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/EX14

http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN03

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at [prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) - its a great way to build WPF apps.